# Tensorflow Transformer Colab: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core' has no attribute 'compiler'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I tried to import the packages in the Transformer code in [Transformer Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/r2.0rc/site/en/r2/tutorials/text/transformer.ipynb). Is there a updated tensorflow core version?

```
 from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

try:
  !pip install tf-nightly-2.0-preview
except Exception:
  pass
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf

import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I got the following error.

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-22c51fa8bb84> in <module>()
      5 except Exception:
      6   pass
----> 7 import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
      8 import tensorflow as tf
      9 

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in <module>()
     96 
     97 # We still need all the names that are toplevel on tensorflow_core
---> 98 from tensorflow_core import *
     99 
    100 # These should not be visible in the main tf module.

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core' has no attribute 'compiler'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is from not having tensorflow datasets installed. Use `pip3 install tensorflow-datasets` for installing and run the script again. Here is a useful TF-datasets offical [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/overview).